# PermitRootLogin No and Sudo user – Where is the difference?

Tags: sudo, login, root

So, I've read that I shouldn't permit root logins by disabling them in my sshd_config. I understand how that might make a server safer, but if I have a user that is allowed to do "su root" and log into the server as root that way, what difference does it make? Seems like having a user that can log into the root user that way kinda defeats the purpose of the "PermitRootLogin" option.

Comment: `PermitRootLogin No` in the sshd_config, prevents someone to become root on another machine, because he or she has rights to do so and ssh'ing into your machine as root, even though their account doesn't have root privileges on the new machine. Yes it can be prevented by not allowing authorized key pairs to be stored etc, but sysadmins are absent minded sometimes and one temporary setting, forgotten to be removed can come back to bite you in the rear more often than one can imagine. So, having another layer of protection is not bad

Comment: Think about this. system1 can ssh into system2 as root and rootlogin is permitted in sshd_config. I have sudo privileges on system1 but not on system2 and think that it is for a good reason, like system1 being development and system2 being production. I can elevate my privileges on system1 and using the permitrootlogin backdoor, I can come to production system as root and try to fix a problem my code has caused, without leaving a trail. This is a big NO-NO by any type of auditing, SOX being the most widely known type.

Comment: Where does this multiple system idea come from? I'm running a single dedicated server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PermitRootLogin No` doesn't prevent root logins entirely, it only prevents root logins through ssh. Enabling this option prevents a class of brute force attacks where an attacker tries to `ssh root@server` with some common passwords (including an empty password, which can work if `PermitEmptyPasswords` is enabled). The point of refusing remote root logins is that `root` is a very common username; by disabling remote root logins you require the attacker to *also* correctly guess a valid username.